# If $A$, $B$, $C$ are connected subsets of $X$ and $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$ and $B\cap C\neq\emptyset$, is $A\cup B\cup C$ connected?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Is my proof acceptable? All of my searches have led me to answers which are too advanced for me to understand and wouldn't be acceptable for my course. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here's what I tried

Proof: For the sake of contradiction, suppose $A \cup B \cup C$ is not connected, and let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be nonempty, disjoint sets such that $\overline {K}_1 \cap K_2 = K_1 \cap \overline{K}_2 = \emptyset$. Construct a set $K_3 = \{p : p \in A \cap K_1\}$ and a set $K_4 = \{p : p \in A \cap K_2\}$. One of these sets must be empty, for otherwise this would be a separation of $A$ and contradict the fact that $A$ is connected. This means that all of $A$'s points are either in $K_3$ or $K_4$, which means they are all in $K_1$ or $K_2$. We will say they are all in $K_1$. A similar line of reasoning can be used to conclude that all of $B$'s points are in either $K_1$ or in $K_2$, and the same with $C$'s points. $B$'s points must be in $K_1$, for otherwise $K_1 \cap K_2 \neq \emptyset$ because $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$. The same line of reasoning can be used to conclude that all of $C$'s points are in $K_1$. Thus $K_2$ must be empty and there is no separation of $A \cup B \cup C$.

Comment: You can simply write $\{p : p \in X\}$ as "$X$" by the way.

Comment: Sounds like you've got it.

Comment: Have you not proven anywhere that a union of two connected sets with nonempty intersection is connected? If not, I think it would even make quite a stylistically nice answer to just prove that and then apply recursively to $(A \cup B) \cup C$. (This doesn't change very much, but it means you don't have to write "by the same line of reasoning" quite so often)

Comment: Thank you friends, it is much appreciated. And that is a good idea Izaak, I will keep that method in mind

Comment: From what you've given, you cannot conclude from $K_3$ being empty that $A \subset K_4$, or vice versa. There is no reason $A$ has to intersect either $K_1$ or $K_2$. And even if it does, there is no reason it has to be contained in their union. (This is not a problem with your intended proof - only that you left some key elements out in writing it down.)